# Best way to create schemas in SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, bash

i would like to ask for help with my backend flux.

I'm starting to use SQL now, and i have some background in noSQL databases, but i don't know SQL much, so i'm having some trouble finding out how to register my schemas.

I'm using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysq), and the way that i can create schemas is calling the method query, like:

```
myInstance.query(    'CREATE TABLE users (
  id       INT PRIMARY  KEY  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name     VARCHAR(100) NULL NULL,
  email    VARCHAR(100) NULL NULL,
  password VARCHAR(100) NULL NULL
)');
```

The problem with this solution is: this code will run in every server initialization.

So, i would like to know how to check if the schema already exists, and.. is this a good solution?? I was thinking in a bash script that creates all schemas, them i don't need this if statements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are calling a "schema" is really a "table".  Hence, `create table` statement, rather than `create schema`.  This is very important.  Perhaps this part of the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-default-schema.html) will help you understand the difference.

There are four very different constructs:

- Database Server     -- how you connect to one or more databases
- Database Instance   -- a grouping of objects, typically a unit of backup and storage
- Schemas             -- a grouping of objects (which may be within a database), typically a unit of permissions
- Tables              -- where data is stored

Note that different database systems have slightly different variations on these.

Of course, "tables" have schemas, which is why it is easy to get confused.

Generally, the management of the database is handled separately from user applications.  That is, the DBA (which might also be the developer) would create the database, manage access, handle backup/recovery, and other things.  The application would simply connect to the database and assume that the correct tables and data are there.

That is, under most circumstances, you wouldn't be creating tables in application code.  Just use the tables that should already have been created for your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify you sql statement to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (…
```

That way the code will run on server init, but not do anything and also not fail when the tables are already there. See the [corresponding mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#idm140438607707488).

Contrary to the answer you got, to have the SQL statements in application code is not that uncommon for backends.